# Pass a variable between two scripts?

Tags: python, tkinter, scripting, statusbar, yield

I'm having issues passing variables between two scripts in python without ending the imported script.  I would like for the status bar in my tkinter GUI to update to reflect what number the counter in `script2` is on.  I've included the code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import script2

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

def runScript():
    var = script2.information()

button1 = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=runScript)
button1.pack()

var = StringVar()
var.set('Waiting for Input...')
status = Label(root, textvariable=var, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

`script2.py` would be:

```
#script2
import time

def information():
    variable = 0
    while variable < 500:
        yield variable
        variable += 1
        print(variable)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I understand that this has to do with generators, but my understanding was that `yield` would pause the loop, send the data to the original program, let it process it, and then un-pause the loop.  Is there a better way of understanding this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, `script2.information()` is a generator function which means you will have to manually iterate the generator object returned on the first call it to get successive values.

For another, `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading. One thing you *can* do is schedule for a function to be called after a certain amount of time using the universal widget method [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html). In this case, it can be used to schedule a call to an (added) function that iterates the generator object after it's been created by calling `script2.information()` and updates the `StringVar()` widget accordingly each time it's called.

You also need to change `script2.py` so it doesn't call `time.sleep()`. Doing so will make your tkinter GUI program hang whenever it's called (since it temporarily interrupts execution of the tkinter `mainloop()`).

Modified `script2.py`:

```
import time

def information():
    variable = 0
    while variable < 60:  # changed from 500 for testing
        yield variable
        variable += 1
        print(variable)
#        time.sleep(1)  # don't call in tkinter programs
```

main script:

```
from tkinter import *
import script2

DELAY = 100  # in millisecs

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

def do_update(gen, var):
    try:
        next_value = next(gen)
    except StopIteration:
        var.set('Done!')
    else:
        var.set(next_value)
        root.after(DELAY, do_update, gen, var)  # call again after delay

def run_script(var):
    gen = script2.information()  # create generator object
    do_update(gen, var)  # start iterating generator and updating var

var = StringVar()
var.set('Waiting for Input...')

button1 = Button(root, text="Run script!", command=lambda: run_script(var))
button1.pack()

status = Label(root, textvariable=var, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `information` generator returns an iterator, you will need to save the iterator instance and call `next()` on it to get the next value. To change the `var`, you will need to use `.set()` to change it.

```
from tkinter import *
import script2

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

def runScript():
    var.set(next(info)) # set the variable as the "next" result of the info generator

info = script2.information() # the info is an iterator 

button1 = Button(root, text="Click Me!", command=runScript)
button1.pack()

var = StringVar()
var.set('Waiting for Input...')
status = Label(root, textvariable=var, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

The `script2` can stay the same. But I recommend you to **not** use `time.sleep`, it wouldn't work as you expect it to! It will just make your program not respond for the given seconds.

You will need to use `root.after` if you want to increment to continue till StopIteration, just change `runScript` to this::

```
def runScript():
    global info
    try:
        var.set(next(info)) # set the variable as the "next" result of the info generator
    except StopIteration:
        var.set('Finished')
        info = script2.information()
    else:
        root.after(1, runScript)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  When I make your suggested changes, though, my status bar becomes "<generator object...>", and the loop in script2 does not continue.

Comment: Also, I only put time into the other script to simulate something difficult and time consuming happening.  I appreciate the nugget of info on that, though!

Comment: It worked fine for me.. did you changed my code to this: `var.set(information())` ? You will need to do exactly what I did.

Comment: Does it increment every time you press the button?  Or does it go through the numbers one at a time until the loop is finished, sort of like a progress meter?  I'm trying to achieve the latter.  I think I did a poor job of explaining that.

Comment: Ok then, do you still want to use a generator? A generator works extremely well with "increment every time you press the button" Since a generator pauses when encounter a yield, and continue when it's called next() again.... But for the latter, I don't think it's necessary